# The way to join multiple relative clauses

Tags: commas, relative-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions, oxford-comma, which-that

One sentence [on this website](https://www.religion-online.org/article/capital-gains/) says:

> It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange silly, that encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing (economists know this last by the odd term "rent seeking").

Apparently, the sentence contains three relative clauses introduced by *that*. Each of them seems to be a restrictive clause.

Many advise against the use of commas before restrictive clauses; however, the rule becomes opaque when multiple restrictive clauses are joined. One may use *and* to underline the coordination, and it is debatable whether an Oxford comma should be used.

In addition, according to Otto Jespersen, *who* and *which* "are often preferred in the second of two coordinated relative clauses", while in American English, most usage manuals recommend against using *which* with restrictive clauses.

Consequently, there may be five options:

> (1) It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange **silly, that** encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing.

> (2) It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange **silly, and that** encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing.

> (3) It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange **silly and that** encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing.

> (4) It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange **silly, and which** encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing.

> (5) It is caused chiefly by kleptocratic governments or private interests in league with governments that make market exchange unprofitable, that make investment in producing something to exchange **silly and which** encourage achieving private wealth at the cost of other people’s wealth instead of by working, saving and inventing.

Are all of the five options equally acceptable? If not, which one is considered the most objectionable?

Comment: Could you estimate the %ge of the way through the passage the sentence occurs, please, nomen? // Offhand, I'd use (2) if I really thought there had to be running script (the sentence is difficult to construe ... and that's even after you've dropped the terminal expansive parenthetical). // There are previous threads discussing relativisers 'that', 'which', and 'who', and defining / non-defining relative clauses and punctuation. I'd say mixing the two types in a sentence is getting close to violating the Orwellian injunction to avoid the outlandish.

Comment: ... Perhaps that was over-prescriptive. << The house that Buckminster Lesser built, which we've almost reached now, is really beautiful. >> But there are only two relative clauses here (admittedly mixed), and they're short and sweet. As is the matrix sentence.

Comment: "that ... and which" sounds a bit odd to me, but using "that" then "which" (without "and") seems acceptable. This sort of sentence is based more on piling up evidence in a heap, than offering a particularly precise logical structure, so I don't think it matters much (are you really requiring something that meets every condition or just most of them?) I'm not sure you'll get any authoritative judgment on what is or isn't acceptable - even the basic rules about relative clauses are disputed by some people and admit some exceptions.

Comment: The original is correct and uses the rhetorical devices of anaphora and asyndeton. You could solve your whole problem, though, by removing the second *that* and replacing the third with *and*.

Comment: The sentence lists 3 bad things kleptocrats do. I wouldn't join them further, though @TinfoilHat has a helpful idea with *and*.

Comment: I'm not even sure that these are restrictive clauses. I interpret it as a list of ways that kleptocrats impact market-based economies.